# Why changing an object before updating is wrong?

Tags: reactjs

As we already know, in order to trigger a new render, react compares states variables based on type and value (`===`). However when we want to update objects, we have to clone any nested object inside to avoid mutating the actual object, hence working on a new copy every time.

For example, let's say that we have the following object:

```
const [object, setObject] = useState({a: {b: {c: {a: 'a'}}}})
setObject(prev=>{...prev, {b: {...prev.b, c: {...prev.b.c, a: 'new value'}}}}
```

It means that I had to clone everything until this point since any object has it own actual representation in the memory.

However, if do the following:

```
object.b.c.a = 'new value'
setObject({...object})
```

it will trigger the render, since the main reference of the object has been changed. What's wrong with this, what could happen by using it?

The only think I can think of is that I don't use the prev state of the object and if I use timers it can cause some issues since it  won't be able to take the recent state. but in general if I don't use timers in here, is there any issue with it?

Answer (score 0):

### Not modifying state:

Changes to `state` in `App` won't affect the `value` in `Child`

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ user: { name: "Alex" } });

  const handleClick = () => {
    setState({ ...state, user: { ...state.user, name: "Tom" } });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
      <p>Your current name is: {state.user.name}</p>
      <Child user={state.user} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Child({ user }) {
  // assign props once
  const [value, setValue] = useState(user);

  // state doesn't change
  return <p>Your previous name is: {value.name}</p>;
}
```

[image: Edit peaceful-stallman-13ymdi]

### Modifying state

Changes to `state` in `App` affect `value` in `Child` although it shouldn't

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ user: { name: "Alex" } });

  const handleClick = () => {
    state.user.name = "Tom";
    setState({ ...state });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
      <p>Your current name is: {state.user.name}</p>
      <Child user={state.user} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Child({ user }) {
  // assign props once
  const [value, setValue] = useState(user);

  // state changes although it shouldn't
  return <p>Your previous name is: {value.name}</p>;
}
```

[image: Edit kind-cdn-wp0gdo]

Comment: so what is the correct way to change the user? to clone only its object and assign it to the original object or should I clone everything up to this point? cause if I have to clone ...state it's going to re-render anyway, so I'm not sure what it the right way to do that